# React : Component does use old state when re-render why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi if got a little problem. In my state i use an array of objects. When I delete one item out of the array, the component does render correctly without the object which has been deletet. If I now try to open anoter object(which leeds to a render), the component does render with the previous state again where the deleted object is still in the array.

Here is my code

IMPORTANT: I use React.memo component for BewohnerListInactive. Without React.memo it works fine.. But How can I use React.memo without having the issue?

```
function Controller({ data: defaultData }) {
  console.log("render controller");

  const [bewohnerData, setBewohnerData] = React.useState(defaultData);

  console.log(bewohnerData);

  /// is beeing used to change active to true which leads to diffrent view

  function changeActive(room) {
    const newBewohnerData = bewohnerData.map((bewohner) => {
      if (bewohner.active === true && bewohner.room !== room) {
        bewohner.active = false;
      }
      if (bewohner.room === room) {
        bewohner.active = true;
      }
      return bewohner;
    });
    setBewohnerData(newBewohnerData);
  }

  /// is beeing used to change the view again to "inactive"

  function close(room) {
    const newBewohnerData = bewohnerData.map((bewohner) => {
      if (bewohner.room === room) {
        bewohner.active = false;
      }
      return bewohner;
    });
    setBewohnerData(newBewohnerData);
  }

  /// here i'm deleting the object out of the array. everything works fine and the component is beeing renderd correctly.

  function removeBewohner(room) {
    setBewohnerData(bewohnerData.filter((bew) => bew.room !== room));
  }

  return (
    <>
      {bewohnerData.map((bewohner) =>
        bewohner.active ? (
          <BewohnerListActive
            room={bewohner.room}
            name={bewohner.name}
            medikamente={bewohner.medikamente}
            close={() => close(bewohner.room)}
            removeMedikament={removeMedikament}
            addMedikament={addMedikament}
            addBestellung={addBestellung}
            removeBewohner={() => removeBewohner(bewohner.room)}
            key={bewohner.room}
          />
        ) : (
          <BewohnerListInactive
            room={bewohner.room}
            name={bewohner.name}
            active={bewohner.active}
            changeActive={() => changeActive(bewohner.room)}
            key={bewohner.room}
          />
        ),
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: It could be a closure problem. You could use the callback functionality of your state setters so your state's are always fresh. setSomeState((oldState) => { return newState } )

Comment: Thx Jazz for your fast response. But this doesn't work. I've just found out, that i only have that issue when i use React.memo for the <BewohnerListInactive> component. Without React.memo everything works fine... hmmm

Comment: `console.log` is not a reliable way to find out if your component has new props / should re-render. Use an `useEffect` hook with dependency on `bewohnerData`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `React.memo` on `BewohnerListActive` or `BewohnerListInactive` won't help you at all, since the identities of `close`, `removeBewohner` and `changeActive` change on each render *anyway*.
(And as they say, premature optimization is the root of all evil, so maybe get rid of the `React.memo()`s until you've identified those components' rerenders are the real bottlenecks.)

That said, when dealing with state mutations that need the old data to compute new data, [use the functional update form](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

Instead of

```
setBewohnerData(bewohnerData.filter((bew) => bew.room !== room));
```

do

```
setBewohnerData(bewohnerData => bewohnerData.filter((bew) => bew.room !== room));
```

to ensure you're working with the latest `bewohnerData` value.

The same applies for the other functions dealing with the old `bewohnerData`.

(You might also consider using `useReducer` for `bewohnerData`. It might be easier to formulate your state modifications using it.)

Comment: Allright thanks for the advice in the 2. Part. I'll definetly do so. The problem you see bcs of the identiti change of the function